# Force a non-breaking line for a horizontal scroll box?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Using only CSS, I need to make the dark boxes (the links) line up in one unbreaking line, and for the container (temporarily named div.hurrdurr) to have a horizontal scroll bar when the line of links gets longer than it. I also don't want there to be any left over space when it's scrolling. The links will be changed dynamically, so I can't use a set width, as far as I know.

I only need this to work in the newest Firefox, as that's the only thing I'll be using to display the page.

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 1000px;">
    <head>
        <title>Hurrr</title>
        <style>
            div.contain {
                background-color: #999999;
                height: 90px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            div.hurrdurr {
                background-color: #CCCCCC;
                white-space: nowrap;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            div.hurrdurr a {
                width: 60px;
                height: 20px;
                margin-right: 8px;
                margin-top: 4px;
                background-color: #333333;
                color: #CCCCCC;
                text-align: center;

                float: left;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contain">
            <div class="hurrdurr">
                <a class="durr">1/25</a>
                <a class="durr">2/25</a>
                <a class="durr">3/25</a>
                <a class="durr">4/25</a>
                <a class="durr">5/25</a>
                <a class="durr">6/25</a>
                <a class="durr">7/25</a>
                <a class="durr">8/25</a>
                <a class="durr">9/25</a>
                <a class="durr">10/25</a>
                <a class="durr">11/25</a>
                <a class="durr">12/25</a>
                <a class="durr">13/25</a>
                <a class="durr">14/25</a>
                <a class="durr">15/25</a>
                <a class="durr">16/25</a>
                <a class="durr">17/25</a>
                <a class="durr">18/25</a>
                <a class="durr">19/25</a>
                <a class="durr">20/25</a>
                <a class="durr">21/25</a>
                <a class="durr">22/25</a>
                <a class="durr">23/25</a>
                <a class="durr">24/25</a>
                <a class="durr">25/25</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always consider posting your code (or at least part of) with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `float:left`from your `div.hurrdurr a` and that should give you scrolling.

Comment: Thank you so much.

I'd been googling around for hours and trying different things. Almost every post I read said that the `float: left;` was the solution. I guess I didn't think about exactly what it was applied to.

Once again; Thank you. You've made my day.